# How to allow user to use RDP connection to windows azure Windows Server VM instance?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, azure, user-management, windows-server-2012-r2

I created a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM instance in Windows Azure and I can connect to it. I created a new user account for my friend (*not admin). Opened new MSTSC instance and tried to connect to created account on given VM. Connection failed with message "connection failed due to user account not having rights for remote access to the system" (sorry for my bad translation). What shell be done to provide user with rights for remote access in Windows Server R2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" Ryan /add
```

The above command will add the user account named "Ryan" to the "Remote Desktop Users" group on the local computer.